# « En tant que » quel sujet ?

Tags: linguistique, syntaxe, sujet

Je crois mais je voudrais être sûre (car je ne trouve pas d'explication sur internet) que lorsqu'on commence une phrase par « en tant que », le sujet doit obligatoirement correspondre.

Par exemple, « En tant que femme, je suis d'accord avec vous » (correct) et « En tant que femme, vos idées ne me plaisent pas du tout » (incorrect).

J'aimerais aussi savoir (si j'ai raison) comment on appellerait ce genre d'erreur syntaxique. **Est-ce qu'on peut appeler ça un solécisme ou pas ? J'ai assuré à quelqu'un que c'en était un mais il doute et je n'ai pas trouvé de preuve concrète.**

J'ajouterais que ma question ultime porte sur « comme tout bon » (mais c'est encore plus dur à trouver). *Comme tout bon chrétien, je vais à la messe le dimanche* (correct). *Comme tout bon chrétien, le péché me dégoûte* (incorrect). Et donc encore, quelle serait la catégorie de cette erreur ?

Comment: Tu as raison, ce serait une faute. Ça s'appelle un dangling modifier... Je chercherai le nom en français.

Comment: En tant que **non** expert mais dont le français est la langue maternelle, la seconde option ne me choque pas et me semble relativement courante.

Comment: Je vais mettre un +1, car je n'aurais jamais considéré ca comme une erreur, même si je comprends l'idée...

Comment: @Tensibai je suis d'accord que c'est relativement courant, mais les formulations courantes ne sont pas toujours correctes (loin s'en faut), et ça reste intéressant de vérifier ce cas particulier !

Comment: @Kerkyra J'ai insisté sur le point non expert pour ça, ce n'est qu'une remarque sur l'usage. Sur le fond je n'en ai aucune idée.

Comment: Il ne me semble pas que ce soit incorrect, ou bien si ça l'est, l'erreur n'est pas liée à "en tant que". En effet, on peut remplacer par "comme femme", "étant une femme", "faisant partie des femmes" et l'ambiguïté reste possible. Inversement et en conséquence, il me semble la première phrase "en tant que femme, je suis d'accord avec vous" peut être ambigüe car la femme peut être "vous" (j'approuve vos propos car vous les tenez en tant que femme)..

Comment: Disons que ce n'est pas incorrect, c'est une ambiguité (comme il y en a tant dans les conversations) qui devrait être levée par la connaissance du contexte. Si c'est une femme qui s'adresse à un homme, il n'y a aucun doute.

Comment: @Tensibai Hi. To confuse the matter further, what do you think of the construction "***En tant que commandant*** de ce groupe, gérer ce genre de situation est ***pour moi*** une question d’honneur"? :)

Comment: @Alone-zee in this case the commandant is obviously the locutor and the subject of the whole sentence as you emphasized it nicely, there's no doubt about who's 'en tant que commandant' refers to, whereas on the other sentences it's possible to confuse who's ' en tant que X' refers to, but I'm probably biased :)

Answer (score 5):

Cette faute de syntaxe (parfois un effet de style chez certains écrivains) s'appelle une **anacoluthe** : le début de la phrase est suivi d'une construction qu'on n'attend pas.
Il s'agit d'une anomalie effectivement courante, qui peut éventuellement amener des contresens mais toujours une confusion dans la compréhension de la phrase : « En entrant dans le magasin (qui, elle ou moi ?), la caissière me sourit. »

Comment: Mais je ne pense pas que cela soit une erreur, forcément.

Comment: @Lambie Exact, comme tant d'autres effets de rhétorique, du pléonasme au zeugme. C'est le rédacteur qui fait tout…

Comment: Hum, les instincts des locuteurs natifs et des francophiles plus expérimentés me font douter le mien. Mais comme cette construction a tendance à déclencher des malentendus, qu'elle soit une faute ou non, je dirais que c'est à éviter ... mais peut-être qu'elle soit moins problématique en français que ne soient les « dangling modifiers » en anglais.

Comment: Un cliché assumé des journalistes de faits divers est de titrer  "ivre virgule" les articles qui s'y prêtent. Exemple, "Ivre, il se trompe de maison et s'endort dans le lit du voisin".  Il y a quelques jours, le manque d'attention a conduit à quelque chose du genre "Ivre, sa voiture quitte la route". A se demander qui a trop bu.

Comment: Merci à tous, en gros il semble y avoir consensus pour dire que ce n'est pas tout à fait correct comme je l'imaginais, c'est effectivement la même logique dans ivre virgule. Mais aussi je voulais savoir si on ne pouvait pas appeler ça un solécisme?

Comment: @Paulina Suivant la définition principale de "solécisme", il me semble absolûment que oui : _**Faute contre la syntaxe au regard de** la grammaire ou de **l'usage jugé correct** à une époque donnée_ (TLFI). Par ailleurs je suis étonné de voir tant de mansuétude dans les commentaires : personnellement je suis toujours heurté en entendant ou lisant la tournure incorrecte. Selon mes (trop vieux) souvenirs, la formule qui commence la phrase serait **une apposition au sujet**, justement : ce qui valide l'idée qu'il y aurait bien une règle, qui ne devrait pas être transgressée.

Comment: @Chambaron "du pléonasme au zeugme" : j'ai un peu de mal à accepter de mettre dans le même sac des tournures qui me semblent relever le plus souvent, tantôt de la faute (pléonasme), tantôt de la finesse d'expression pour un effet recherché (zeugme).

Comment: @cFreed Tous ces mots caractérisent à l'origine (XVIe et XVIIe siècles) des figures de style résultant de l'analyse savante du latin classique. On les a cultivées dans les classes de rhétorique. La condamnation n'est venue qu'ensuite, pour fustiger les rustres. Le pléonasme n'est que le plus emblématique de ces usages ambigus, mais chacune des 150 figures de style a sa face dorée et sa face obscure.